# vSphere web-services sample fails with "The server sent HTTP status code 200: OK"

Tags: java, web-services, templates, virtual-machine, vsphere

I want to deploy VM templates from vSphere/vCenter programmatically and so as a start I downloaded the SDK zip from VMware and copied the VMClone.java from the web services sdk into an Eclipse project and run it using this code:

```
String[] myargs = new String[12];
myargs[0] = "--url";
myargs[1] = "https://192.168.0.91:9443";
myargs[2] = "--username";
myargs[3] = "[myuser]";
myargs[4] = "--password";
myargs[5] = "[mypassword].";
myargs[6] = "--datacentername";
myargs[7] = "LaptopIkor";
myargs[8] = "--vmpath";
myargs[9] = "[datastore1]/liferayTomcat/liferayTomcat.vmx";
myargs[10] = "--clonename";
myargs[11] = "DriverCreation1";
com.vmware.vm.VMClone.main(myargs);
```

(it's just a sample setup, so no privacy issues with above code)
(yes this code is not very nice, it's just for testing)

But this fails with following message/stacktrace:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 200: OK
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
at $Proxy35.retrieveServiceContent(Unknown Source)
at com.vmware.vm.VMCreate.connect(VMCreate.java:287)
at com.vmware.vm.VMCreate.main(VMCreate.java:1047)
at (my own class with above code)
```

This also happens with VMCreate and when using the samples.jar instead of copying the source files. Any idea how to resolve this?

The url points to a win2008 server with vCenter Server installed, including vSphere Web Client.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How did you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
myargs[1] = "https://192.168.0.91:9443";
```

try to

```
myargs[1] = "https://192.168.0.91/sdk";
```